# Выбор студента с самой высокой оценкой из группы

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть таблица `student(id_student, stname, averagemark, id_group)`. Задача - получить по одному студенту из группы с наивысшей оценкой. Вот мой вариант:

```
SELECT s1.stname,
(SELECT max(averagemark) FROM student AS s2 WHERE s2.id_group = s1.id_group) AS averagemark,
s1.id_group
FROM    student AS s1
ORDER BY id_group;
```

Но он выводит всех студентов с самой высокой оценкой (т.е. если в таблице в группе 101 у пяти студентов самая высокая оценка - результат покажет всех пятерых. А нужен один)

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: `select top 1`?

Comment: Из этих 5 - нужен студент отобранный по какому-то определённому принципу? Или просто один любой студент? Если любой из этой пятёрки - то допишите `TOP 1`

Comment: @andreycha так не работает. Если в главный select добавить top 1, то в результате будет только одна строка - для всей таблицы

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Делим таблицу на партиции с помощью `over` и `partition by`, сортируя содержимое партиций по убыванию оценок, т.о. образом в каждой партиции получаем максимальную оценку в первой строке. Дальше выбираем из партиций все первые записи (`where num = 1`).

```
select stname, averagemark, id_group
from
(
    select *, row_number() over (partition by id_group order by averagemark desc) num
    from students
) parts
where num = 1
```