# Ограничение количества строк с IN

Tags: sql

Есть SQL запрос:

```
SELECT * FROM technologies WHERE technology_category_id IN (1,2,3)
```

Можно ли одним запросом вывести по шесть строк для каждого `id`, которые внутри `IN`? `LIMIT` ограничивает общее количество результатов.

Comment: Могу предложить использовать `union` и 3 запроса, но решение оочень костыльное.

Comment: Я уже сделал просто три запроса и оно работает. Но хочется какого-то красивого решения

Comment: [посмотрите вот этот вопрос, очень похож на ваш](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/563539/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2-mysql-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b1%d1%86%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8f%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b5-2%d1%85-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Можно использовать [партиционирование](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/563057/106):

```
select * from
(
    select *, row_number() over (partition by technology_category_id order by technology_category_id) num
    from technologies
    where technology_category_id in (1,2,3)
) tech
where num <= 6
```

В `order by` задайте нужный вам порядок сортировки, если хотите выводить определенные шесть записей.